# How to convert a string into a DateTime in a trasmogrifier step?

Tags: plone, transmogrifier

I need to convert a string into a DateTime during a trasmogrification. Something like this:

```
[set-startDate]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.inserter
condition = python: item.has_key('startDate')
key = string:startDate
value = python: <conversion to DateTime>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the doc of [collective.transmogrifier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.transmogrifier), I've found my answer:

```
[set-startDate]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.inserter
condition = python: item.has_key('startDate')
key = string:startDate
value = python: modules['DateTime'].DateTime(item['startDate'])
```